# Fill color between two coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

Question: How can I fill the region between O(0,0) and A(1,1)?

This is what I've done so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=2.5cm,y=2.5cm,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xmin=-3,
xmax=3,
ymin=-3,
ymax=3,
xtick={-2,...,2},
ytick={-2,...,2},]
\draw [samples=50,rotate around={0:(0,0)},xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,line width=0.8pt,color=wrwrwr,domain=-1.5:1.5,<->,name path=C1] plot (\x,{(\x)^2/2.0/0.5});
\draw [line width=0.8pt,color=sexdts,domain=-2.0:2,<->] plot(\x,{(-0--1*\x)/1});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=black] (-1.5,2.5) node {$y=x^2$};
\draw[color=black] (-1.5,-2) node {$y=x$};
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.40,-0.25) node [rotate=00]{O(0 , 0)};
\draw [fill=black] (1,1) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.40,1.00) node [rotate=00]{A(1 , 1)};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possibility is `\tikzfillbetween` but does your code come from some automatic tool?

Because:

- you uselessly loaded `pgf` (it is already loaded by `tikz`)
- the `scriptsize` environment within the `tikzpicture` does nothing, use the option `scale=...`, instead
- the formulae of your line and your parabola are uselessly complicated (I've changed them)
- your color definitions are strange.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45, scale=.9]
\begin{axis}[set layers,
x=2.5cm,y=2.5cm,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xmin=-3,
xmax=3,
ymin=-3,
ymax=3,
xtick={-2,...,2},
ytick={-2,...,2},]
\draw [samples=50,rotate around={0:(0,0)},xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,line width=0.8pt,color=wrwrwr,domain=-1.5:1.5,<->,name path=C1] plot (\x,{(\x)^2});
\draw [line width=0.8pt,color=sexdts,domain=-2.0:2,<->, name path=retta] plot(\x,{\x});
\draw[color=black] (-1.5,2.5) node {$y=x^2$};
\draw[color=black] (-1.5,-2) node {$y=x$};
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.40,-0.25) node [rotate=00]{O(0 , 0)};
\draw [fill=black] (1,1) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.40,1.00) node [rotate=00]{A(1 , 1)};
\tikzfillbetween[
    on layer=axis background,
    of=C1 and retta,
    soft clip={domain=0:1}
    ] {red};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it looks a lot like code generated by `geogebra` that has been partially cleaned up. https://www.geogebra.org/

Comment: Yes exactly i accepted codes are generated from geogebra. I am beginner for graph drawing in tikzpgf

Comment: Thanks to you both. For sharing some useful information. Definitely this will increase my limit of knowledge in drwaing

Comment: Both answers are very useful for me.

Comment: an mwe? What does it mean?

Comment: @snehal A minimal working example, see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @snehal Please note that I have also edited my answer to put the options for having the filling in the background.

Answer (score 5):

With the `fillbetween` library of `pgfplots` (`\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}`) you can color the part between two curves. To do this, a `soft clip` is used which restricts the coloring to a specific area.

This area can be delimited by a path such as a rectangle:

```
\plot [orange] fill between [of=C1 and C2,
        soft clip={(0,0) rectangle(1,1)}
        ];
```

or by an interval of the domain of the functions:

```
\plot [orange] fill between [of=C1 and C2,
        soft clip={domain=0:1}
        ];
```

[image: plot]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=2.5cm,y=2.5cm,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xmin=-3,
xmax=3,
ymin=-3,
ymax=3,
xtick={-2,...,2},
ytick={-2,...,2},]
\draw [samples=50,rotate around={0:(0,0)},xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,line width=0.8pt,color=wrwrwr,domain=-1.5:1.5,<->,name path=C1] plot (\x,{(\x)^2/2.0/0.5});
\draw [line width=0.8pt,color=sexdts,domain=-2.0:2,<->,name path=C2] plot(\x,{(-0--1*\x)/1});
\plot [orange] fill between [of=C1 and C2,
    soft clip={(0,0) rectangle(1,1)}
    %soft clip={domain=0:1}
    ];
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=black] (-1.5,2.5) node {$y=x^2$};
\draw[color=black] (-1.5,-2) node {$y=x$};
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.40,-0.25) node [rotate=00]{O(0 , 0)};
\draw [fill=black] (1,1) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.40,1.00) node [rotate=00]{A(1 , 1)};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```